# Google Sign-in Cannot read property 'load' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, google-signin

I attempting to create a Google Sign-in in an Angular application, but I keep getting the following error:

> Cannot read property 'load' of undefined

I actually had this working just an hour ago, but now it seems to be having a loading issue - I'm pretty sure something is out of sync somewhere, but I'm not sure what I can do about it?

Just for clarity, my app does not load onto the login page from start, I navigate to it afterwards using the address bar in Chrome (don't know if that would make a difference). I have got the right client id in there, I just replaced it for this question for security.

**login.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  public auth2: any;
  user: string;
  gapi: any;

  public googleInit() {
    this.gapi.load('auth2', () => {
      this.auth2 = this.gapi.auth2.init({
        client_id: 'client_id.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
        scope: 'profile email'
      });
      this.attachSignin(document.getElementById('googleBtn'));
    });
  }

  public attachSignin(element) {
    this.auth2.attachClickHandler(element, {},
      (googleUser) => {

        let profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        console.log('Token || ' + googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token);
        console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId());
        console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
        console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
        console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());
        //YOUR CODE HERE
        this.user = "";

      }, (error) => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 2));
      });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.googleInit();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**login.component.html**

```
<div id="googleBtn">Login w/ Google</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `load` method is on the `gapi` instance variable, and I do not see anything assigned to `gapi`. How should that variable be initialized?

Comment: It's initialized in the google script that's declared in the index page `<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>`

Comment: @WebDevelopWolf that script creates a global variable called `gapi`. But you are referencing a instance variable, `this.gapi`. How does the global `gapi` variable relate to the `gapi` instance variable in your class? If you want to reference the global variable then replace `this.gapi` with `gapi`.

Comment: Sorry only just seen this - I changed it to a declared variable - but I'm still getting the same problem - how can I create / reference the global variable?